# Graphical authentication agent doesn't trigger once I changed from desktop environment

Tags: unity, mate, policykit

I recently switched from Mate to Unity (just installed unity-desktop and removed mate-desktop) with all dependencies and suddenly, the graphical polkit window.

For example, when I try to launch Synaptic, it does absolutely nothing, or, when cleaning system with Ubuntu Tweak, it does nothing as well (it used to ask for password), installation via Software Center neither. But on the other hand, gksu and sudo commands launched from terminal or alt+f2 work.

I have set administrator rights for my account. "sudo whoami" returns "root".
Any ideas what is wrong?

```
~$ which pkexec
/usr/bin/pkexec
~$ synaptic-pkexec
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic ===
Authentication is required to run the Synaptic Package Manager
Authenticating as: My Name,,, (miskopo)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
```

Then it launches Synaptic normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you removed `mate-desktop` and all its dependencies, you will also have removed `mate-polkit`, which provides authentication dialogs for the Mate desktop.

To use `pkexec` from within a GUI you will need a replacement.  Type in the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install policykit-1-gnome
```